# How to concatenate two charcters in c?

Tags: c, string, char, string.h

I am new to c .

When i try to do

```
char a = 'h';
Char b = 'j';

Strcat(a,b);
```

I get an error because a and b must be two strings .
So how can i do this ?

Comment: Your compiler will fail to understand `Char` and `Strcat`, I don't believe what you're saying.

Comment: What do you mean?  If you want to create a string that contains those two characters, you could do `char c[3]; c[0] = a; c[1] = b; c[2] = 0;`

Comment: you declared `a` and `b`. What is `j` ?

Comment: In C all string functions like `strcat()` expect the arguments to be nul-terminated strings. (C strings end with `'\0'` (ASCII `0`) which marks the end of the string). Therefore, to treat the combined characters as a string, you need storage for each character `+1` for the *nul-terminating* character. And each `a` and `b` need to be strings. If a were, e.g. `char a[8] = "h";` and `char b[] = "j"`;, then you could `strcat (a, b);` with the result in `a` being `"hj"`.

Comment: Or `char c[] = { a, b, '\0' };`

Comment: It would be better to learn from a book or other learning resource. Trial and error does not work well with C

Comment: But "concatenate two characters" makes about as much sense (to me) as "concatenate two integers".

Comment: When creating a [mcve] please make sure it demonstrates only the problem you ask about, and don't contain other unrelated problems. Other unrelated problems tends to distract from the actual problem.

Comment: @WilliamPursell In many languages characters are simply one-element strings, so it makes sense if you're coming from one of those languages. Or even if you don't know those languages and just think of them conceptually the same way.

Comment: @WilliamPursell And I'll bet a newbie would have no problem with thinking of concatenating integers, e.g. concatenate 12 with 45 to get 1245.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completion here's a list of possible solutions:

gsamaras (esiest for your case):
`char str[] = {a, b, '\0'};`

Through an array:

```
char* string = (char*)malloc(3);
string[0] = 'a';
string[1] = 'b';
string[2] = '\0';
```

Generically:

```
char* str1 = "a";
char* str2 = "b";
size_t str1_len = 2;
size_t str2_len = 2;
char* new_str = (char*)malloc(str1_len - 1 + str2_len);
memcpy(new_str, str1, str1_len - 1);
memcpy(new_str + str1_len, str2, str2_len);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`strcat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) is a method used to concatenate strings. In your cases you have characters, so you shouldn't use this method.

Instead, you can create the string yourself, like this for example:

```
char str[] = {a, b, '\0'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Take these two characters as string and then use strcat() function.

```
char a[] = "h";
char b[] = "j";

strcat(a,b);

printf("%s",a);
```